# Java 8 streaming API using with Map

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I see this code snippet at my work. I am unable to get correct picture of what is going on here. I tried using debugger to get values, but debugger is not helpful here.

```
public static void process (ErrorCat exc, String toFind) {
          Map<String, Function<Error, Error>>  translate = new HashMap<>(); 
            translate.put("foo", new classThatimplementsFunction());
             translate.put("bar", new classThatimplementsFunction())
            List<Error> Errors = Lists.newArrayList();
            List<Error> retErrors = Lists.newArrayList();
            retErrors.addAll(exc.getErrors());
            translate.keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(k->toFind.contains(k))
                    .forEach(key->exc.getErrors() // from here I dont follow
                            .stream()
                            .forEach(e->{retErrors.remove(e); Errors.add(translate.get(key).apply(e));}));
```

I have commented above where I am starting to have difficulty following.
is second `ForEach` executed for each `key` that is filtered. If so, then `retErrors.remove(e);` during second iteration of key will have no effect (since retErrors will be empty after first iteration)

Comment: Couldn't you ask the person who wrote this piece of code? You'll have certainly a better explanation

Comment: I wish that person continued at work...

Comment: Oh that's rather unfortunate then.. That's why you should comment your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like somebody let an IDE automagically convert imperative code to streams.

I think `retErrors.remove(e)` is there to leave `retErrors` empty if any translators matched `toFind`.  This is my best guess of the code's original intent:

```
List<Error> errors = translate.keySet().stream()
                            .filter(toFind::contains)
                            .map(translate::get)
                            .flatMap(translator -> exc.getErrors().stream().map(translator))
                            .collect(toList());

List<Error> retErrors = errors.isEmpty() 
                            ? new ArrayList<>(exc.getErrors()) 
                            : Collections.emptyList();
```